# Apply appendChild() with more than one option using only Javascript

Tags: javascript, jquery, arrays, dom-events

I have a button that when pushed, it creates a new row. That row consists of selects,texts, and cells. My select box, when created has a default option 't'. How do I list multiple options without using html?

I tried to create a new textnode and when I do the appendChild for both options, I get them both on the same line. I need the second variable 'u' to be an entirely new option. Any help is most appreciated.

HTML

```
<button onclick="AddRow()"></button>
```

Javascript

```
function addRow(){

    var optionObject = {};
    var table=document.getElementById('table2'),tr,input,row,cell

    tr=document.createElement('tr');
    tr.setAttribute("class","rows");
    tr.id = "AddedRow";                 
    field = document.createElement("select");// this is where the select box is     
    var z = document.createElement("option"); //this is to create an option for the select box
    z.setAttribute("value", "Choose"); // this is to give it a default value
    var t = document.createTextNode("Select a Current Job");// this is to give it a default field name
    var u = document.createTextNode("Select yoyo");// this is to give it a default field name
    z.appendChild(t);// append the default field name to the option
    z.appendChild(u);// append the default field name to the option

    field.appendChild(z);// append the option to the select box   
    field.setAttribute("id","jobSelector");
    //field.setAttribute("class","celltimes5a");
    field.setAttribute("class","celltimesSelect");

    var jobCol=document.createElement('td');
    jobCol.setAttribute("class","celltimes5c");
    tr.appendChild(field);
    tr.appendChild(jobCol);                             

    td=document.createElement('td');
    td.setAttribute("class",'celltimes4c');
    td.id = "row14total";

    tr.appendChild(td);
    table.appendChild(tr);

}
```

Comment: What does you for loop do? The code, once the button is clicked doesn't reproduce anything on the output, your function name is not equal to the call

Comment: I was using it for something else, but you are right, the first loop doesnt do anything. the second loop does.

Comment: Can you put it on a fiddle?

Answer (score 0):

needed to create a another new option and append it as well

```
var z = document.createElement("option"); //this is to create an option for the select box
                    z.setAttribute("value", "Choose"); // this is to give it a default value
                    var w = document.createElement("option"); //this is to create an option for the select box
                    w.setAttribute("value", "Choose"); // this is to give it a default value
                    var t = document.createTextNode("Select a Current Job");// this is to give it a default field name
                    var u = document.createTextNode("Select yoyo");// this is to give it a default field name
                    z.appendChild(t);// append the default field name to the option
                    w.appendChild(u);// append the default field name to the option
                    field.appendChild(z);// append the option to the select box
                    field.appendChild(w);// append the option to the select box
```